# QComboBox drop down button outside combo box frame

Tags: css, qt, stylesheet, qcombobox

I'm trying to go outside combo box frame with this CSS Qt style sheet:

```
QComboBox#tab_combo {
margin: 0 26px 0 0; /* make room for the arrow */
padding: 2px 1px 2px 1px;
min-width: 19px;
min-height: 14px;
max-height: 14px;
width: 40px;
height: 14px;
//...strip
}
QComboBox#tab_combo::drop-down {
 subcontrol-origin: margin;
 subcontrol-position: center right;

 width: 19px;
 min-width: 19px;
 max-width: 19px;

 height: 14px;
 min-height: 14px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;

border: 1 solid #515151;
}

QComboBox#tab_combo::down-arrow {
 image: url(:/combo_arrow.png);

 min-width: 19px;
 max-width: 19px;
 width: 19px;

 min-height: 14px;
 max-height: 14px;
 height: 14px;
}
```

All success except padding, you can see it on picture ( figure 3 ).

[qcombobox padding http://www.turist.lv/tmp/combo-box-trouble.png](http://www.turist.lv/tmp/combo-box-trouble.png)

Any suggestion ?

Thank you

p.s
How to reproduce:
http://pastebin.com/4ZiYRUmB

**Edit:**
How to solve it:
Need to change QComboBox CSS with this code:

```
padding: 2 -19px 2 1;
width: 59px;
```

Comment: Can I see your QComboBox#tab_combo section? Did you reset padding on QComboBox itself?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to add it, but now its OK.

Comment: Wild shot, but try setting right margin to negative value. I remember that sometimes I had to do such things to achieve some effects on QComboBox. Also make sure that you don't sett padding on QWidget or QComboBox somwhere else. It may inherit some values from other CSS

Comment: Yes, you right, I change padding to: padding: 2 -19px 2 1;  and increased width to 19px and seems it work. Very strange effect, look like QT bug :)

Comment: Qt is mixing painting. When you apply CSS part of your app (even one widget) is painted by underlying style, and part is painted by QtCss Style. There is huge chance, that when you change some properties on QComboBox or its subcontrols padding -19 will shoot your button somwhere ;)

Comment: Also there is huge chance that app will look differently on cerain platforms (i.e. on Mac OS X). I've posted answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change QComboBox padding to negative value